# Nextjs Folder Routing Inside Pages Sub-Folder

Tags: next.js, routes

I am new to Nextjs and Stackoverflow so I will try to describe my issue as best as possible.

I have created the following folder structure in my project:

- pages

  - api folder
  - index.js
  - sys-admin folder

    - createvenue.js
    - createuser.js
    - index.js

Inside sys-admin>index.js, I have a button with an onClick handler that uses next/router to push to the createvenue.js route. When I type in the URL http://localhost:3000/sys-admin/createvenue, I can see the createvenue.js page however, when I click the button in the http://localhost:3000/sys-admin page, I am directed to http://localhost:3000/createvenue which gives me a 404. My understanding was that the folder name (in this case sys-admin) would become the root and would be added to the router path to make the URL http://localhost:3000/sys-admin/createvenue.

Here is my sys-admin>index.js code:

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

export default function CreateCustomer() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const handleSubmit = () => {
    router.push("/createvenue");
  };
  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <button className="btn btn-filled">Create New Customer</button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

Here is my createvenue.js code:

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

export default function CreateVenue() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const handleSubmit = () => {
    router.push("/createusers");
  };
  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter venue name" />
        <button className="btn btn-filled">Next</button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

I've also tried adding /sys-admin to router.push("/sys-admin/createvenue"); but it still doesn't work.

Is there a way to get next/router to add the sys-admin root to the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default Behaviour of the form is to refresh the Page once it submitted. You have to prevent the form event from refreshing the page.

```
 export default function CreateVenue() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    // preventing the form event from refreshing the page
    event.preventDefault()
    router.push("/createusers");
  };
  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={(e)=>handleSubmit(e)}>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter venue name" />
        <button className="btn btn-filled">Next</button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Wonderful, thanks very much! I also amended the push path to router.push("/sys-admin/createusers") and it works perfectly!